# Category Theory Axioms apropos $\mathsf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory

One of the Category Theory axioms I've been provided within some class lecture notes is that  If $X,Y,A,B$ are objects of $\mathcal{C}$ and $(X,Y) \neq (A,B)$ then Hom$_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y) \cap$ Hom$_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B) = \emptyset$.

So I want to verify this axiom for $\mathsf{Set}$, where the morphisms are functions between sets, then for sets $X,Y,A,B$ we let Hom$_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y) \cap$ Hom$_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B) \neq \emptyset$ and I pick $f$ from this intersection. So $f$ takes values from $X$ and $A$, but I can only say from this either $A \subseteq X$ **or** $X \subseteq A$, but not *and*, therefore not giving me equality.

Is there a way to resolve this? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$First: saying that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ means that $f$ assigns an element of $Y$ to *every* element $x \in X$. Indeed, the domain of a function is entirely determined by the function. So assuming $f \in \Hom_{\mathsf{Set}}(X,Y) \cap \Hom_{\mathsf{Set}}(A,B)$ tells you that $X = A$ on the nose.

Second: in order to prove that these hom-sets are disjoint, you'll need to know *exactly* what they are. Saying "$\Hom_{\mathsf{Set}}(A,B)$ is the set of functions from $A$ to $B$" is not a precise definition until you've defined what a function is. Once you have a correct, precise definition of function, it'll be fairly straightforward that any function determines its domain and codomain (hence if a function has two domains, they must be the same, and likewise for codomains).

Here's a precise definition you could use in order to define the category $\mathsf{Set}$:

**Definition** A function from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is a pair $(f,B)$ where $f \subseteq A \times B$ and, for all $a \in A$, there is a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$.

The ordered pair is really neccesary here, otherwise we would have $\varnothing \in \Hom_{\mathsf{Set}}(\varnothing, \varnothing) \cap \Hom_{\mathsf{Set}}(\varnothing, \{\varnothing\})$ for example.

Comment: So are we saying f and its restriction to a subset of its domain are distinct maps?

Comment: Yes. With this definition, if $(f,B)$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ and $A' \subseteq A$, then the restriction of $(f,B)$ to $A'$ is simply $(f \cap (A' \times B), B)$. If $A' \neq A$ then there is some $a \in A \setminus A'$; the definition of function tells us that there is some $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$. However, $(a,b) \notin f \cap (A' \times B)$, so $f \neq f \cap (A' \times B)$, showing $f$ is not equal to its restriction.